# Unit Of Work - related repository

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I've 10 POCO class. 
I'm using a simple repository pattern with unit of work with IRespoitory interface and UnitOf work class.

Is it right (normal) put all my IRepository in a single UnitOfWork instance?

Namely:
10 POCO class - 10 instance of IRepository - Only one UnitOfWork class which contains all 10 repository

```
UnitOfWork
{
IRepository<Customer> CustomerRepository {get; set;}
IRepository<Customer> CustomerRepository {get; set;}
IRepository<Customer> CustomerRepository {get; set;}
// the same for all others 7 POCo class
// ..other stff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little like the **EF DataContext**.

**DataContext of EntityFramework** is a **unit of work** and a little like a **repository** (or collection of your **repositories**).

I prefer to separate these things and use a dependency injection framework (like structuremap).

You can ask **structuremap** for `IRepository<Customer>` and it will give you the instance.

Separate **UoW** from your **Repositories**.

You can have one **UoW** class (with methods like: `SubmitChanges`) and then Your **Repositories** (each with methods like: `Add, Delete, ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is right (normal) with one Unit Of Work class/instance contains all repositories (of POCO classes).

The UoW brings 2 important things/advantages for me;

1. The obvious one is the ACID (Atomic, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) transactions, as only one dbcontext tracks and updates all db changes.
2. [Unit of Work reduce a lot of dependency Injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439226/net-core-unit-of-work-generic-repository-pattern)

Here is a complete example of using UoW with repositories;

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IRepository<Customer> Customers { get; }
    IRepository<Order> Orders { get; }
    // the same for all others 8 POCO class

    Task<int> SaveAsync();
}
```

=============================================================

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public IRepository<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }
    public IRepository<Order> Orders { get; private set; }
    // the same for all others 8 POCO class

    private readonly MyDBContext _Context;

    public UnitOfWork(MyDBContext context)
    {
        _dbContext       = context;
        Customers        = new Repository<Customer>(_dbContext);
        Orders           = new Repository<Order>(_dbContext);
        // the same for all others 8 POCO class
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveAsync()
    {
        return await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

AS you can see in the above implementation that one dbContext has been used to generate all repositories. This will bring the ACID functionality.

And in your Services/Controller (or anywhere you want to use your repositories), you just need to inject only 1 UoW and can access all your repositories as:

```
    _uow.Customers.Add(new Customer());
    _uow.Ordres.Update(order);
    _uow.SaveAsync();
```