# .net core - unit of work generic repository pattern

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am Looking to migrate a large project that gathers information about products. The current application uses CSLA as its framework (traditional aspx forms).

I am wanting to migrate / develop the application over to .net core 2.1. I have experience of developing in MVC (4+ years) and some recent exposure to .net core.

I am wanting to use EF Core to call the existing stored procedures. I am looking at using the Unit of Work Generic repository design pattern. I have used the repository pattern before and found it very useful.

As part of the functionality that exists within the current process, it contains a Master table and an Edits table structure format. When someone edits a product, a new row is inserted into the Edits table. Once approved by an admin, it then inserts / updates the current row in the Master table.

Has using the ‘Unit of Work / generic repository pattern’ worked well for other developers within .net core 2.1?

What issues have you come across?
My aim is to produce a high performance efficient driven application.

Any other thoughts and suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework, it already uses repository pattern. `DbContext` is your Unit of Work and `DbSet<Entity>` is your repository. Entity framework is designed in a way that forces coupling with application and that is fine for certain scenarios. Don't use repository pattern if you use Entity Framework.

Comment: yes i am leaning towards using EF. I have read that the Unity of Work pattern already exists. Providing another layer within the Model / Service Layer would allow me to implement the 'unit of work' / generic repository pattern to interact with the DBContext. Im looking at possibly calling stored procedures to operate the CRUD as there is some logic within Stored Procedures. Another approach would be to use the context / entity as appose to using stored procedures. Having the sp's has its benefits such as separation to edit / tweak the SQL instead of re-compiling the app for any SQL change etc

Answer (score 10):

Personally, i use Unit of Work to reduce a lot of dependency Injection. I can have a database Unit of work and once i use dependency Injection to inject the Database context in that Unit of work, i don't need to inject each model repository where i want to use them, but will just access the repositories from the unit of work. This also helps me only instantiate a repository only when i need it in a specific method.

```
public interface IDatabaseUnitOfWork
{
    DbContext DatabaseContext { get; }
    Task<bool> Save();

    IBaseRepository<UserAccount> UserAccountRepository { get; }
}

public class DatabaseUnitOfWork : IDatabaseUnitOfWork
{
    private IBaseRepository<UserAccount> _userAccountRepository;

    public DatabaseUnitOfWork(DbContext databaseContext)
    {
        DatabaseContext = databaseContext;
    }

    public DbContext DatabaseContext { get; private set; }

    public async Task<bool> Save()
    {
        try
        {
            int _save = await DatabaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }

    public IBaseRepository<UserAccount> UserAccountRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userAccountRepository == null)
            {
                _userAccountRepository = new BaseRepository<UserAccount>(DatabaseContext);
            }
            return _userAccountRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseUnitOfWork, DatabaseUnitOfWork>();
services.AddScoped<IServiceUnitOfWork, ServiceUnitOfWork>();
```

Finally

```
public class DemoClass
    {
        private IServiceUnitOfWork _serviceUnitOfWork;
        public DemoClass(IServiceUnitOfWork serviceUnitOfWork)
        {
            _serviceUnitOfWork = serviceUnitOfWork;
        }

        Public bool CreateUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount){
            await _serviceUnitOfWork.UserAccountRepository.Add(userAccount);
            return await _serviceUnitOfWork.Save();
        }

       ----
   }
```

**UPDATE**

GENERIC BASE REPOSITORY

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    Task<bool> Add(T entity);

    Task<List<T>> GetAll();

    Task<List<T>> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);

    Task<List<T>> SearchBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> searchBy, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);

    Task<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);

    Task<bool> Update(T entity);

    Task<bool> Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> identity, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes);

    Task<bool> Delete(T entity);

}

public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private DbContext _ctx;

    public BaseRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _ctx = context;
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Add(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _ctx.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            return  await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return  await Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
    {
        return _ctx.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var result = _ctx.Set<T>().Where(i => true);

        foreach (var includeExpression in includes)
            result = result.Include(includeExpression);

        return await result.ToListAsync();
    }


    public virtual async Task<List<T>> SearchBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> searchBy, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var result = _ctx.Set<T>().Where(searchBy);

        foreach (var includeExpression in includes)
            result = result.Include(includeExpression);

        return await result.ToListAsync();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds by predicate.
    /// http://appetere.com/post/passing-include-statements-into-a-repository
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate">The predicate.</param>
    /// <param name="includes">The includes.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual async Task<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var result = _ctx.Set<T>().Where(predicate);

        foreach (var includeExpression in includes)
            result = result.Include(includeExpression);

        return await result.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Update(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            _ctx.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
            _ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

            return  await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return  await Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> identity, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var results = _ctx.Set<T>().Where(identity);

        foreach (var includeExpression in includes)
            results = results.Include(includeExpression);
        try
        {
            _ctx.Set<T>().RemoveRange(results);
            return  await Task.FromResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return  await Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Delete(T entity)
    {
        _ctx.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        return await Task.FromResult(true);
    }

}
```

EXTENDING THE BASE REPOSITORY (eg. **DeleteAllAccounts**)

```
public interface IUserAccountRepository : IBaseRepository<UserAccount>
    {
        Task DeleteAllAccounts();
    }

    public class UserAccountRepository : BaseRepository<UserAccount>, IUserAccountRepository
    {
        private DbContext _databaseContext;
        public UserAccountRepository(DbContext databaseContext) : base(databaseContext)
        {
            _databaseContext = databaseContext;
        }

        public async Task DeleteAllAccounts()
        {
            ......
        }
    }
```

So instead of using *`_userAccountRepository = new BaseRepository<UserAccount>(DatabaseContext);`* you would use **`_userAccountRepository = new UserAccountRepository(DatabaseContext);`**

Comment: Good example. I assume within your UserAccountRepository that you have your BL and data access to EF accessing the method serviceUnitOfWork.UserAccountRepository.Add(userAccount) for example.?

Comment: yes i i do. but what i normally do is create a generic repository (**BaseRepository**) with basic methods such as `Add`, `Update`, `Delete`. Then if i want something beyoud basic CRUD operations, I extend the base repository for a specific model.

Comment: Your repositories are leaky abstractions. Say for example I don't want to use EF anymore and want to replace this implementation with LiteDb database. LiteDb doesn't support `Expression<Func<>>`, so it is impossible to replace EF with anything else. Also how do you do transactions? Looking at your repositories, you can't.

Comment: All you will do is write another repository for LiteDb or manually interpret what `Expression<Func<>>` is and then translate it to something *LiteDb* would understand. This way, you can take advantage of full features offered by an ORM or direct database connection and leaves you with great flexibility. I once went with the way you are suggesting and the results were not very pleasing.

Comment: with your example of the DemoClass, would you be calling that from your controller action? i always like to have the controller light as possible. Example; 

public ActionResult index(){  
DemoClass demo = new DemoClass();
var model = demo.CreateUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount)
return View(model);
}

Comment: @McKabue having opened this post, it has led me to questioning my own style of developing. In particular knowing where the best place to my BL.In past projects i put my BL within the repository, same repository that would save against the initiated DBContext. 

Where do you normally place your BL with developing the Unit of work pattern?
I keep reading that a service layer would be best to put the BL in, but seems like it adds unnecessary abstraction layer though. 

Whats your thoughts? thanks

Comment: @Paul i create services for related domain logic, eg. *`AccountManagerService`*. Since these services could become too many, i create another UnitOfWork, eg. *`ServiceUnitOfWork`*, similar to *`DatabaseUnitOfWork`* that carries all the services.

Comment: @McKabue Is there a reason why your UoW example does not implement IDisposable?  Is this particular to dotnet core? I'm genuinely curious because I am implementing a similar UoW/repo pattern.

Comment: Your `DatabaseUnitOfWork` is configured as Singleton and it has a dependency on `DbContext`. Did it ever occur to you that your `DbContext` might never get disposed at all?

Comment: @atiyar i have since changed this to scoped

Answer (score 3):

I'm going with a classic "it depends".  Essentially `DbSet<>` is a repository, and `DbContext` is a unit of work.  But that doesn't mean you can't use the repository pattern or unit of work pattern at a higher level of abstraction.

My advice is don't use it until you need it.  I have used a unit or work pattern with EF Core and found it very useful in the situation where you are working with multiple `DbContext`s, or multiple database providers.  I haven't found any other instance to use it in.

I tend not to use a generic repository ever, because I prefer to encapsulate my queries, and keep them out of my `Controller` or `Pages`.

---

Updated to answer the comment below:

That's a great question, and not so easily answered, and certainly out of the scope of StackOverflow.com, because craftsmanship is generally considered opinion. There's a stack exchange for questions directly related to code craftsmanship https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

I will however say how excited for you I am that you are at least raising the question.

My personal opinion is to recommend 'Domain Driven Design' There are a lot of free resources on the subject, but the go to source would be the book by Eric Evans.

In essence, your business logic is the core, and all dependencies point inward. So even a 'service layer' would not have your business logic in it.

Comment: @adminvincet  Having opened this post, it has led me to questioning my own style of developing. In particular knowing where the best place to my BL.In past projects i put my BL within the repository, same repository that would save against the initiated DBContext. Where do you normally place your BL with developing the Unit of work pattern? I keep reading that a service layer would be best to put the BL in, but seems like it adds unnecessary abstraction layer though. Whats your thoughts? thanks

Comment: @Paul See updated answer. I will say that it is an opinion, and that other answers are not wrong.